# Transpose multiple columns into rows

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, oracle19c

**Oracle 12c/19c**

I have inherited some data which is in a table in the below format (please don't beat me down for why would someone store the data in this format etc - I get it but have to work with what I have).  Business wants the data with columns transposed into rows for months (Target format shown below).

I am able to get the data I want using the big union query listed below but wanted to see if anyone had any better/efficient way to write it.  I am also thinking of creating a nightly job to transform this data into the new format (or create a mview).

**Source:**

```
ORDER_ID
ORDER_YEAR
QTY_JAN
QTY_FEB
QTY_MAR
QTY_APR
QTY_MAY
QTY_JUN
QTY_JUL
QTY_AUG
QTY_SEP
QTY_OCT
QTY_NOV
QTY_DEC
```

**Target:**

```
ORDER_ID
ORDER_YEAR
ORDER_MONTH
QTY
```

**Query:**

```
select order_id, order_year, '01' order_month, sum(qty_jan) qty
from order_quantity
group by order_id, order_year
union
select order_id, order_year, '02' order_month, sum(qty_feb) qty
from order_quantity
group by order_id, order_year
union
select order_id, order_year, '03' order_month, sum(qty_mar) qty
from order_quantity
group by order_id, order_year
union
select order_id, order_year, '04' order_month, sum(qty_apr) qty
from order_quantity
group by order_id, order_year
union
select order_id, order_year, '05' order_month, sum(qty_may) qty
from order_quantity
group by order_id, order_year
union
select order_id, order_year, '06' order_month, sum(qty_jun) qty
from order_quantity
group by order_id, order_year
union
select order_id, order_year, '07' order_month, sum(qty_jul) qty
from order_quantity
group by order_id, order_year
union
select order_id, order_year, '08' order_month, sum(qty_aug) qty
from order_quantity
group by order_id, order_year
union
select order_id, order_year, '09' order_month, sum(qty_sep) qty
from order_quantity
group by order_id, order_year
union
select order_id, order_year, '10' order_month, sum(qty_oct) qty
from order_quantity
group by order_id, order_year
union
select order_id, order_year, '11' order_month, sum(qty_nov) qty
from order_quantity
group by order_id, order_year
union
select order_id, order_year, '12' order_month, sum(qty_dec) qty
from order_quantity
group by order_id, order_year
;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with the `UNPIVOT` operator, available since Oracle 11.1.

I included months with NULL quantity in the output (easy to modify if you don't need them). I also created **two** columns for each month - one for the month name and the other for the position of the month within the year. The name can be used in the `SELECT` clause (it will be shown in the output), while the "position" is only used in the `ORDER BY` clause.

I created sample data for testing in the `WITH` clause. Of course, that is not part of the real-life solution. Use your actual table and column names in the main query. I only included the first three months - it should be easy for you to change to include all 12 months.

```
with
  order_quantity (order_id, order_year, qty_jan, qty_feb, qty_mar) as (
    select 1001, 2018, 300, 450, 200 from dual union all
    select 1001, 2019, 400, 250, null from dual union all
    select 1001, 2020, 300, null, 200 from dual union all
    select 1002, 2019, 540, 230, null from dual union all
    select 1002, 2020, null, 300, 800 from dual
  )
select order_id, order_year, order_month, qty
from   order_quantity
unpivot include nulls (
    qty for (order_month, pos) in ( qty_jan as ('January' , 1)
                                  , qty_feb as ('February', 2)
                                  , qty_mar as ('March'   , 3)
                                  )
                      )
order by order_id, order_year, pos
;
```

Output:

```
  ORDER_ID ORDER_YEAR ORDER_MONTH        QTY
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------
      1001       2018 January            300
      1001       2018 February           450
      1001       2018 March              200
      1001       2019 January            400
      1001       2019 February           250
      1001       2019 March                 
      1001       2020 January            300
      1001       2020 February              
      1001       2020 March              200
      1002       2019 January            540
      1002       2019 February           230
      1002       2019 March                 
      1002       2020 January               
      1002       2020 February           300
      1002       2020 March              800
```

Comment: OMG - you are awesome!  This query works like a charm!!  Unpivot did come to my mind and I played around with it but couldn't get to work.  Thanks a lot again!!!

Have a couple of questions:
1. What does the number 1, 2 in "qty_jan as ('January' , 1)" or "qty_feb as ('February', 2)" do?
2. Can I filter so that I do not get the rows with 0 quantity?  Or should I wrap it in another subquery and filter "qty <> 0"?

Thanks again for your quick and perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hierarchy query as follows:

```
SELECT ORDER_ID, ORDER_YEAR,
       DECODE(LVL,1,'January',2,'February', ...., 12,'December') AS ORDER_MONTH,
       DECODE(LVL,1,QTY_JAN,2,QTY_FEB, ...., 12,QTY_DEC) AS QTY
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT LEVEL AS LVL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12);
```

Comment: You are missing some `connect by` conditions - rows should be related to prior rows by `order_id` and `order_year`. Or, in Oracle 12 and higher, you can do the `connect by` in a `lateral` clause; it avoids the cross-linked rows issue and it is more efficient at the same time.

Comment: I think simple `CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12` is enough for this query

Comment: You think wrong. I provided test data in my answer, use it and you will see.

Comment: @mathguy In question, There are 12 columns and that represents each month so 12 rows need to be generated always. so the condition in the connect by is correct.

Comment: You seem to not understand how CONNECT BY works. Please do me a big favor: take the data from my answer, run your query on it. Trust me, you will understand what I mean. The issue is not generating "enough" rows, it is generating "exponentially many" rows - the same row will appear many, many times. This is a very general property of CONNECT BY, so you better learn it as soon as possible, if you are going to use CONNECT BY.

Comment: Ohh Yes!! You are right @mathguy, I know how it works but still, I messed it up. See the answer now!! and thanks for pointing it.

Comment: @Tejash - your query works perfectly as well.  Glad to know another way to achieve the same results.  Outstanding!!  Great way to use CONNECT BY.  Thanks for your help.

"CROSS JOIN" in your query is displayed twice.  So if you can edit your answer and remove it, the query will work for the next person using it.